# Render camera preview on a Texture with target GL_TEXTURE_2D

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, shader, render-to-texture

I'm trying to render the camera preview on an OpenGL Texture with target `GL_TEXTURE_2D`. I'm very well aware of SurfaceTexture but I cannot use it because it only works with `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`. In the documentation of SurfaceTexture, it's written :

```
 Each time the texture is bound it must be bound to the GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES target rather than the GL_TEXTURE_2D target
```

I cannot use `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` because, I'll have to make a lot of changes in my existing code.

Is there a way to achieve this which is fast too ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I can come up with is to listen to the `SurfaceTexture` and when new frame comes you just redraw it on a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` target.

When coming to the OpenGL ES field, things can get really complicated. Let me try to explain this to you with my limited experience. Some pseudocode below.

1. If you want to render the camera data to a off-screen texture, you'll need a off-screen frame buffer. Some functions you may need.

   ```
   GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
   GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, frames, 0);
   GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, frameRender, 0);
   GLES20.glActiveTexture(ActiveTexture);
   GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
   GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA,
               width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA,
               GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, directIntBuffer);
   GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER,
               frameRender[0]);
   GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER,
               GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
   GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
   GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frames[0]);
   GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
               GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
               textures[0], 0);
   GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
               GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER,
               frameRender[0]);
   ```
2. Compile your `vertex` and `fragment` shaders and link your `program`.
3. Prepare your `vertex`, `textureCoordinates` and `drawList` buffers.
4. Bind your `SurfaceTexture` from camera to a certain GL_TEXTURE

   ```
   GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
   GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, cameraSurfaceTextureHandle);
   ```
5. `GLES20.glUseProgram(yourProgram)`, link all the above together, and `GLES20.glDrawElements`

Comment: Can you provide me with some code ? I'm pretty new to OpenGL. Just the OpenGL function calls.

Comment: If you look at https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java, the `RECMETHOD_FBO` path shows the render-to-texture part. Most of the camera-related activities show the SurfaceTexture part.

Comment: Btw, the preview I'm getting is distorted. Here's a small video - 
http://tosc.in/omerjerk/SCR_20150318_023219.mp4

Can anyone please comment as to what might be going wrong here ?

Comment: What is `directIntBuffer` here? Is it filled with pixels or empty with the proper size? Also, what is in the initialization, and what is done in the onDrawFrame method?

Comment: I can relate it to this line in grafika: // Create texture storage.
            GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
                    GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

Comment: of all the provided answers I were looking for, your parameters were the ones which worked. Thanks!

Comment: In part 4, I thought you need the target to be the GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES type not TEXTURE_2D since SurfaceTexture uses a GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES.  It actually works if it's TEXTURE_2D?