# Copying data from one texture to another - opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, render-to-texture

I'm rendering my camera preview in android on a `SurfaceTexure`. This `SurfaceTexture` is bound to target `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`.
I want to copy the texture data from this `SurfaceTexture` object to my custom OpenGL texture which is bound to `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

My onFrameAvailable callback is as follows :

```
@Override
public void onFrameAvailable(final SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    glView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
            //TODO: Copy this texture to the custom texture
        }
    });
}
```

I have the custom texture object created already.

Can anyone help me with the copying part ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is to bind the texture at a color attachment to an FBO, select that FBO as active and use glCopyTexImage to copy from the FBO into the destination texture.

Comment: Can you please provide me with some OpenGL pseudo code ?

Comment: Btw, have you considered the point that both textures are bound to different targets ?

Comment: I added a link in a comment to the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003414/ -- it shows the FBO setup in an Android app. The activity in question is rendering the scene to an FBO, and then essentially blitting that texture twice (once to the display, once to a video encoder). I think you want to do something similar, where you render the external texture full screen to the FBO, and then use the backing texture however you want.

Comment: @omerjerk: It doesn't matter which target each texture is bound to. The FBO acts as the adaptor.